# Cual es este lenguaje de programacion?

Tags: base-de-datos

Tengo que modificar un formato del programa VisorUS (Que también es muy raro) y no logro identificar que lenguaje maneja el formato.

Se que manejamos una base de datos de donde se toman estas consultas pero no parece el SQL que suelo manejar.

¿Se trata de una version diferente de SQL? ¿Esta combinado con otro lenguaje? ¿O es algo totalmente diferente?

```
begin
  IF [cdsCYP."IMPUCYP"] = 0 then
  begin
     Impsi := 0;
     Impex := [cdsCYP."IMPCYP"];
     GpoSubtex := GpoSubtex + [cdsCYP."IMPCYP"];
  end
  else
  begin
     Impex := 0;
     Impsi := [cdsCYP."IMPCYP"];
     GpoSubtsi := GpoSubtsi + [cdsCYP."IMPCYP"];
  end;

  GpoImporte := GpoImporte + [cdsCYP."NETCYP"];
  GpoSubtotal := GpoSubtotal + [cdsCYP."IMPCYP"];
  GpoImpuestos := GpoImpuestos + [cdsCYP."IMPUCYP"];


    s:=[cdsCYP."sefcyp"] ;
f:=[cdsCYP."fofcyp"];

FEC2:=FN_SQLQUERY('SELECT fedcyp FROM maecyp WHERE SERFOL='+QUOTEDSTR([s])+' AND numfol='+Str([f]) ,'fedcyp');

FEC3:=FN_SQLQUERY('SELECT NUMAGT FROM maecyp WHERE SERFOL='+QUOTEDSTR([s])+' AND numfol='+Str([f]) ,'NUMAGT');

                 MEMO34.VISIBLE:= TRUE;
                 MEMO14.VISIBLE:= FALSE;

    Z:=abs([cdsCYP."FEDCYP"]-FEC2);
       W:=[cdsCYP."NUMC|TE"];

 if    FEC3=9
    THEN begin   b:=abs([cdsCYP."NETCYP"]) * 0.10;
                 MEMO34.VISIBLE:= FALSE;
                 MEMO14.VISIBLE:= TRUE;
    end
     else if    W =1770
     then begin
                 b:=abs([cdsCYP."NETCYP"]) * 0.10;
                 MEMO34.VISIBLE:= FALSE;
                 MEMO14.VISIBLE:= TRUE;
     end
     else if    W =149
     then begin
                 b:=abs([cdsCYP."NETCYP"]) * 0.10;
                 MEMO34.VISIBLE:= FALSE;
                 MEMO14.VISIBLE:= TRUE;
     end
     else BEGIN  b:=0;
                 MEMO34.VISIBLE:= TRUE;
                 MEMO14.VISIBLE:= FALSE;
     end;

          d:=abs([cdsCYP."NETCYP"]) * 0.10 ;
     ab:=ab+b;

    FC:=FC+D;

end
```

El código ya fue modificado por alguien antes que yo, dejo la modificación para que les ayude a identificarlo.

Comment: al parecer es pascalscript

Comment: Hola riku28 esto se parece principalmente a Oracle PLSQL que es donde creo que se usa `:=` pero no creo que se use `+` para la concatenación de cadenas (`||`). De lo contrario, esto me parece SQL. ¿Definitivamente no puedes ver en qué base de datos se está ejecutando?